# How can I integrate electronic faxing with MS Fax?

Tags: windows, fax

I am in need of an efax (generic, not to be confused with the company) solution, but I have a couple of requirements from current software that we're running.  Basically the problem is that we have software that only supports MS Fax and WinFax natively.

We currently have 3 fax lines connected to 3 US Robotics external modems.  These, in turn, are connected into a local server which is running MS Fax.  This solution causes failures constantly, though.  We would like to move to an electronic fax service, but we'd need to keep the same server architecture, just get rid of the phone lines/modems.  This means that it needs to be Windows, too, so no really awesome open source for us:o(

Through my Googling, I haven't found a solution that will integrate with MS Fax (or WinFax) so that it will forward fax requests to an efax service rather than to the modems.  Are there any suggestions?

*TL;DR: are there any efax services with clients that will allow MS Fax (or WinFax) to forward and receive messages?*

Comment: Sorry, per the FAQ, product or service recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Is there somewhere else?  Is this something that will be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I would contact [Esker Software about VSIfax](http://www.esker.com/solutions/fax_servers/solutions/fax_software_unix.asp) to see what their integration options are and if anything will work with the software setup you have. I've used it extensively in bundled software solutions and find it flexible enough to work...